# uninitialized constant ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 with ActiveResource.
I have an issue in production that says:

```
ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed. Response code = 404. Response message = Not Found.
```

So I tried to treat it the same way I treat `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
    render_404
  end

  rescue_from ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound do |e|
    render_404
  end

  def render_404
    respond_to do |type|
      type.html { render template: 'shared/404_not_found', layout: 'application', status: '404 Not Found' }
      type.all  { render nothing: true, status: '404 Not Found' }
    end
  end
end
```

But now, when I deploy, I get an error telling me that:

```
/apps/com.example/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `eval': uninitialized constant ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound (NameError)
```

I don't really get it. I tried with a `if defined?(ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound)` but then it falls back to the previous behavior.

Any idea of how to treat this issue ?

Thanks !

**EDIT:** For the moment I used the following code but I'm not really happy with it.

```
rescue_from Exception do |e|
  e.is_a?(ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound) ? render_404 : raise
end
```

Comment: What rails version are you using? This class doesn't exist at Rails 3.

Comment: Yeah it does: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/45d6cd94b3ef2ec77166def41f29188445b35608/activeresource/lib/active_resource/exceptions.rb#L61

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.  Also using `rescue_from ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound` and getting the same error.  Did you come up with a solution or are you still using the global rescue_from Exception hack?  :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, ignore my comment I figured out a solution:

```
rescue_from "ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound" do |e|
  render_404
end
```

Put the exception in quotes so it doesn't try to evaluate it on startup (when, I assume, ActiveResource hasn't loaded yet)